# Appscript Webapp hyperlink not working - The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have created a Web App with different pages: login, dashboard, orders.
I check if the user is logged in, if so will redirect to dashboard.
Dashboard will have link to place order - takes to order page and once order is placed successfully it will redirect to dashboard.

Everything works fine when the app is used standalone, but after I embed in google sites, Hyperlink placed in the Dashboard page (To place orders) is not working with the error message

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://app.neelithal.com' from frame with URL 'https://n-n3gcqx22xvz3sn77god6de7c5ipcta6xrsyulmi-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.

I have tried embedding the appscript in both old and new sites with 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' - still not working.

All the pages are set with base target _top
Auto Redirect is done via `window.self.location.href = redirectUrl;`
-- NOTE - If I use `window.top.location` embeded site will not work - Works only if I use `window.self.location.href`.

For the Hyperlink I am using the below code

`<a class="waves-effect" href="<?!= appUrl ?>?v=dashboard&token=<?!= token ?>">`

-- NOTE I have tried hyperlink target as "_top" "_self" "framename" nothing works - One or the other is broken.

XFrameoption set to ALLOWALL

```
    var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("glogin");
    return tmp.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

Script is executed as ME - Access to everyone even Ananymous - Using Google Login for authentication.

Webapp URL - https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzyx5XDtVYPSN5wt_By55pZGpHMSgTnMN_wQd9uIYuG9N9mPME2/exec

Google Sites Url - with custom url - https://app.neelithal.com

Comment: If the duplicates linked above don't answer your question, Ping me back.