# Google standalone appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications, navigation

I have written a standalone google app script for a google web app. when I open a new window on the click of the submit button i get the following error.

> userCodeAppPanel:23 Unsafe attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://script.google.com' from frame with URL.The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed with the 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' flag, but **has no user activation**.

I have tried to add a dynamic anchor tag and then add a click event on the same . still it does not work.

I have created a dynamic anchor tag with the link and activated the click event .

```
 var templink= url+"?role="+role+"&sheetname="+sheets+"&page=Link2"; // 

var temp="window.open("+"'"+templink+"'"+",'popup','width=1000,height=1000','_top')"; 
var link = document.createElement('a'); 
link.id = 'linkURL'; 
link.setAttribute('target', '_top'); document.body.appendChild(link); link.setAttribute('onclick',temp); document.getElementById("linkURL").click();
```

Comment: Currently you have a client side javascript error somewhere around line 23 maybe.  That's all I can tell you without additional information.  Debugging webapps can be tough but the only way to learn is to do it.  I'll be glad to help but I think your going to have to do the leg work.

Comment: As the error says, you need a user to click something to start navigation. You cannot  automatically navigate anywhere programmatically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: error resolved after automatic click event for anchor tag

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69128777/1595451