# Redirecting a web app to Sheets (script apps)

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have created a web app with the apps script however I am having a problem.
I have several links in a menu to navigate in the application and I have another link that goes to a Sheets file.

I would like this link to open in a new tab in my browser. And this is where I encounter my problem. The Sheets opens in a new tab but I get the following error message in the web app :

"Unsafe attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://script.google.com' from frame with URL 'https://n-psool6bzsn7nbbxcwije73kogaweb6gvevl5w2i-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed with the 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' flag, but has no user activation (aka gesture)"

And when I click on another link, the Sheets opens in the same tab.

Here is the JS that opens the Sheets in a new tab :

```
  function sheets(){
     var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
     var link = document.createElement('a');
     link.href = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oATOMdL5HdCx87YjPS79DVvZee_s6y5_J3t9oloYeZI/edit#gid=0";
     link.id = 'linkURL';
     window.open(document.body.appendChild(link));
     document.getElementById("linkURL").click();        
   }
```

Here is the beginning of one of the html pages (the navigation bar is identical for all pages :

```
<nav id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ">
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
     <input type="button" class="buttonNav" id="buttonSelected" value="Page 1"/>
     <input type="button" class="buttonNav" id="button" value="Page 2" onclick="formulaire()"/>
     <input type="button" class="buttonNav" id="button" value="Page 3" onclick="archives()"/>
<input type="button" class="buttonNav" id="button" value="Sheet" onclick="sheets()"/>
   </div>
   <?var url = getUrl();?><input type="hidden" value="<?= url ?>" id="url"/>
 </nav>
```

And here is the apps script code:

```
function doGet(e){
   if(!e.parameter.page){
     return render('Index');
   }
   else if(e.parameter['page'] == 'Formulaire'){
     var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Formulaire');
     return htmlOutput.evaluate();  
   }
   else if(e.parameter['page'] == 'Index'){
     var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
     return htmlOutput.evaluate();  
   }
   else if(e.parameter['page'] == 'Archives'){
     var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Archives');
     return htmlOutput.evaluate();  
   }
 }

 function getUrl(){
   var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
   return url;
 }
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69128777/google-script-about-redirect-not-working-and-appears-peculiar-error-what-happen) but i don't know how can i apply its in my dev.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification? In this modification, your function of `sheets()` is modified as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function sheets() {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oATOMdL5HdCx87YjPS79DVvZee_s6y5_J3t9oloYeZI/edit#gid=0";
  window.open(url, "_blank");
}
```

- When `sheets()` is run, the URL is opened as a new tab.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### Reference:

- [Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: It's work perfectly, thank's for your help Tanaike !!!

Comment: @devMethodes Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.